# Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, f, k, value = mean(knn.pred != test.setY)) : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

When I run the code below I got this error. How do I solve this error?

This dataset is Caravan Insurance dataset

```
 Caravan <- read.csv(file="~/Desktop/Caravan.csv")
 dim(Caravan)
 table(Purchase)]

 [1] 5822   86
 Purchase
 No  Yes 
 5474  348
```

I am trying to use 5-fold cross-validation approach to determine
the optimal K value with the training data only. The candidate values of K are {3, 4, . . . , 10}.

I am doing a K-fold = 5

```
standardized.X = scale(Caravan[, -86])
var(standardized.X[,1])
var(standardized.X[,2])
test = 1:1000
train.X=standardized.X[-test ,] 
test.X=standardized.X[test ,]
train.Y=Purchase[-test]
test.Y=Purchase[test]
```

#Validation set approach

```
set.seed(2001835)
ntrain=nrow(train.X)
retrainData <- sample(ntrain, 0.7*ntrain)
train.setX <- train.X[retrainData,]
test.setX <- train.X[-retrainData,]
train.setY <- train.Y[retrainData]
test.setY <- train.Y[-retrainData]

F <- 5
set.seed(2001835)
folds <- cut(seq(1,ntrain), breaks = F, labels = FALSE)
folds <- folds[sample(ntrain)]
folds



k = 3:10
ErrCV <- matrix(0, nrow=F, ncol= k)
for (f in 1:F) {
 retrainData <- which(folds != f)
 train.setX <- train.X[retrainData,]
 test.setX <- train.X[-retrainData,]
 train.setY <- train.Y[retrainData]
 test.setY <- train.Y[-retrainData]

 for(k in 3:10){
   # Model fitting
   knn.pred <- knn(train = train.setX, test = test.setX, cl = train.setY, k = k)

   # Error
   ErrCV[f,k]=mean(knn.pred != test.setY)
 }
}
 CV <- apply(ErrCV, 2, mean)
 plot(CV,type="l")
```

When i run the code it kept saying that it is out of bounds

Comment: There are too much unknown variables in your example, we don't know what is `F`, `folds`, `train.X`, `train.Y` so this is not reproducible and we can't help you

Comment: Hi Bastien, I have edited and add in more information will you be able to advise how can I debug the code

Comment: Thanks. Where could we find `Purchase` dataset ?

Comment: Its inside the Caravan data

Comment: How do you obtain it from `Caravan` ?

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Insurance+Company+Benchmark+(COIL+2000)